# Android - Using color attr in pre-lollipop drawables causes exception

Tags: android, attributes, android-drawable

I'm going to use a color attr in my drawable but it only works on API 21+ and crashes on API 18. How to fix this issue?

```
<style name="EasyIntro.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="toggleIndicatorsEnabled">@color/toggleIndicatorsEnabledColor</item>
    </style>

    <color name="toggleIndicatorsEnabledColor">#7f000000</color>

    <attr name="toggleIndicatorsEnabled" format="color|reference"/>

    <item
            android:state_enabled="true"
            android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="?attr/toggleIndicatorsEnabled"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
```

Comment: where is item used ? you must apply the theme then you can use attar reference.

Comment: @SohailZahid I'm already using the EasyIntro.Light theme as a parent and setting that custom theme for the activity in the Manifest.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace for your crash to your question

Answer (score 0):

You are using `?attr` in your drawable and it's causing the issue. You can remove the `attr` and it will work fine.